# Proof of a Gaussian Integral property

Tags: calculus, gaussian-integral

I'm working through some old integrals and I found one that's interesting. I can't quite remember how it's proved, so if someone could set me off in the right direction, it would be really helpful. Thanks!

$\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-ax^2 + bx} dx = \sqrt{ \dfrac{\pi}{a}} e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}$

I've tried change of variable, but I'm not sure this is the right approach.

Comment: try completing square on the exponent.

Comment: Complete the square in the exponential, make a change of variable, and then apply the known properties of the Gaussian integral

Comment: You need to start from the Gaussian integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\pi}.$ Complete the square in the exponential and perform an affine change of variable to transform your original integral into the one given in this comment.

Comment: Ah! Thanks, I have the answer now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is by change of variable. You need to complete the square in the exponent,

$$ -ax^2 + bx = -a\left(x-\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 + \frac{b^2}{4a} $$

so to make this like the standard integral you make the change $y = x-b/2a$.