# Expectation of random varible with normal distribution composed with exponential

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, normal-distribution, expectation

I am trying to find
$\mathbb{E}(e^{-X})$ where $X$ is a random variable with a general normal distribution. I end up with

$$(2\pi \sigma)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x}e^{\left(\frac{-(\mu-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)}dx $$

Tried some transformations and the polar coordinate trick used to derive values of $(2\pi \sigma)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int e^{(\frac{-(\mu-x)^2}{2\sigma^2})}dx $ but haven't been able to come up with anything explicit. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am in despair... do I need to use a numerical method?

If it helps, here is what the integral boils down to
$$(2\pi \sigma)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int \exp\left(-\frac{x(2\sigma - 2\mu +x)}{2\sigma^2}\right)dx $$

Comment: Hint: Complete the square in the exponent. Then make an appropriate substitution. By the way there is a typo in the simplification.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1056502/15941) for ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really ought to remember simple things like completing the square... I am being asked to clarify if this isn't a duplicate question but it seems like it is. Do I delete this then?

Answer (score 0):

*Question:*  Let $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Find $E[e^{-X}]$.

*Answer:*  Let $Z = -X$, so $Z \sim N(m,\sigma^2)$, where $m = -\mu$. You seek $E[e^Z]$ which is just the mean of a Lognormal random variable, with Normal parent $N(m,\sigma^2)$. Thus:

$$E[e^{-X}] = E[e^Z] = e^{m +\frac{\sigma ^2}{2}} \quad \text{ where } m = -\mu$$

If you need help deriving the latter integral step-by-step, this is standard textbook material on the Lognormal.